# how to encrypt an entire folder and continue moving plain files to the folder?

Tags: ubuntu, security, permissions, encryption, decryption

We have a folder on our server where daily files comes in from a remote machine. Everyday we check if the files came in and if so - we download them to our local machine. There are around 20 daily files totaling 30Mb everyday.

Once we download the files we move the files on the server to a subfolder called ARCHIVE (~3Gb). This process is done automatically by our java program.

The files we get are considered 'sensitive' and we wish encrypt the ARCHIVE folder. One way to do that is by encrypting every file that comes in with our java program but before we go this way I was wondering if there's a better way to do it?

Using ubuntu, I was wondering if there's a way to encrypt an entire folder (archive) and allowing us to continue moving files to this folder. In other words, to put all daily plain files in an encrypted folder and when asking to retrieve those files (from the archive) - we'll need to provide a password for decryption.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [EncFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) to create a virtual encrypted partition and then mount it to the folder.

Here's easy to follow [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=148600).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions.  The easiest route to go would be to create a dummy user on the server (named blackbox or whatever you like) and have the folder simply owned by that user.  Then grant sudo permissions to that user to whomever you would otherwise give the encrypted password to.

If that's not sufficient, you can take it a step further with an Encrypted Private Directory:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If encfs does not do it for you (its great and easy to set up but has some security limitations, as the file sizes are still visible and some meta-data can be inferred) You could use pretty much any encryption system on linux - either on another physical disk, or by creating a file and mounting it as a block device.  If you want a cross-platform solution, you could even use Truecrypt !